why is Visual Studio 2022 17.9.6 ignoring #pragma omp parallel for? -- Solved
EDIT:  Leaving the original post for others to find.
Jérôme Richard resolved the problem by explaining the /MP does NOT enable OpenMP.  The correct flag is under the C++/Language properties and is "Open MP Support"
ORIGINAL POST BELOW
I am trying to parallelize a very long-running function in a DLL.  The DLL in question is begin built with the command line:
/JMC
/permissive-
/MP
/ifcOutput "x64\Debug\"
/GS
/W3
/Zc:wchar_t
/ZI
/Gm-
/Od
/sdl
/Fd"x64\Debug\vc143.pdb"
/Zc:inline
/D "_WINDOWS"
/D "_USRDLL"
/D "BOOST_INTERPROCESS_SHARED_DIR_FUNC"
/D "_SILENCE_FPOS_SEEKPOS_DEPRECATION_WARNING"
/D "USE_NEW_CACHE"
/D "_UNICODE"
/D "UNICODE"
/D "_WINDLL"
/D "_DEBUG"
/errorReport:prompt
/WX
/Zc:forScope
/RTC1
/Gd
/MTd
/std:c++17
/FC
/Fa"x64\Debug\"
/EHsc
/nologo
/Fo"x64\Debug\"
/Fp"x64\Debug\MyLib.pch"
/diagnostics:column 

I believe the /MP flag should be allowing the pragma to work.
Due to a classification issue, I can only provide the relevant excerpt.
#include <omp.h>

... 
        int totalThreads = omp_get_num_procs();
        int nThreads = totalThreads;
        if (totalThreads > 6)
        {
            nThreads -= 4;
        }
        else if (totalThreads > 2)
        {
            nThreads -= 2;
        }
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "Total Threads: " << totalThreads << " using: " << nThreads;
        TRACE(ss.str().c_str());
        omp_set_num_threads(nThreads);
#pragma omp parallel for 
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            int avail = omp_get_num_threads();
            stringstream ss;
            ss <<"parallel run: " << i << " of " << avail;
            TRACE(ss.str().c_str());

The TRACE macro executes a real-time UDP logger which reports "Total Threads: 20 using 16" which is what I expected from the TRACE outside of the loop.  The second TRACE reports: "parallel run: 0 of 1". If the for loop were actually being run in parallel, I would expect to see "parallel run: 0 of 16".
The 0 of 1 is what I would expect outside of the loop, as omp_get_num_procs returns 1 for serial areas of code.
What am I missing? There are no warnings.

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function main and all #include directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem (which should preferably be hard-coded into the program). If the problem is in the posted code, then it should be possible for you to create a [mre] out of your posted code. Or are you unable to reproduce the problem when you try this?

Are you nesting any #pragma omp parallel or #pragma omp parallel for directives inside any other such directives?

Did you try calling omp_get_num_threads outside of your parallel for by any chance?  If you have more #pragma omp, try logging it before and after every such pragma.

"I believe the /MP flag should be allowing the pragma to work." No. You should use /openmp to enable it. /MP is for something else. As a result, OpenMP should not be enabled unless flags are missing in this question or another runtime is somehow used. Do not guess for things like this, read the doc ;) (easy to find with any search engine as it took me 1 minute).

Since it is a DLL, symbols like omp_get_num_procs may come from another one, but the loop will not be parallelized by MSVC as long as the /openmp flag is not used, even if omp_get_num_procs returns a value >1 and even if you call omp_set_num_threads with a value >1. It might be from a wrong incompatible runtime if you use multiple compilers in your project or incompatible OpenMP flags. Please provide more information about the whole build process.
